# Wordpress theme: force creation of newly created thumbnail size

Tags: php, image, wordpress, thumbnails

I just added a new Wordpress thumbnail size using `add_image_size` call, but now all the photos I already uploaded are not of the correct size. If I request them, all I get is the original image with `width` and `height` attributes correctly set.

How can I force the creation of that thumb, saving the data to the database as well, given an attachment ID?

Please note I want to do a simple admin operation or execute code from a theme file.

Comment: Try the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an operation to do this from the admin, but I can execute this code from a theme file:

```
require(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$file = str_replace('http://www.example.com/', ABSPATH, $attachment->guid);
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment->ID,
    wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment->ID, $file ) );
```

that recreates all of the thumb sizes at once (don't know if the already created ones are done as well, but it's a one time code execution).

You must replace "www.example.com" with your URL and $attachment with an actual attachment post structure, retrieved with `get_post` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug [#13947](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13947). Instead of `the_post_thumbnail()` use this code in your theme until the bug is fixed:

```
the_post_thumbnail(
    array ( 150, 150 ), // size
    array ( 'class' => 'attachment-post-thumbnail' )
);
```

Comment: Sorry you didn't understand the problem. I don't need need the post thumbnail, but all of the images in the post at a specified size, which got specified after the upload. I use them for a custom coded template for an image gallery. Thanks for your answer anyway.